# On thinking that planarity is nothing but topology?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I've found the following quote on Harary's *Graph Theory*:

> [image]

And I'd like to know what it means. I know about the Kuratwoski theorem, which states that a graph is planar if no subgraph of it is isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ or $K_{5}$ but I have no idea on what is the meaning of the rest of the quote. At the moment, I am having a course on graph theory but I still don't know much what topology is.

- In the quote, he seems to be saying that thinking that planarity is nothing but topology is a problem. Why is that?

Comment: Seems to me that, it points to the fact, that $K_5$ is planar on _torus_, [see](http://www.learner.org/courses/mathilluminated/images/units/4/k5torus.png). $K_{3,3}$ also I think [see](https://www.google.cz/search?q=k+3+3+graph+torus&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=634&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=DmFPVK78Is3naKGDgqgC&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ).

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, but I guess it's because the theorem you mention gives a completely combinatorial description of (non)planar graphs, whereas before people maybe thought that it was a topology problem (computing Euler characteristics and so on).

Comment: I would second Najib.

Comment: @quapka Yes, I've read on Bondy and Murthy's *Graph Theory*, page 6: Although not all graphs are planar, every graph can be drawn on some surface so that its edges intersect only at their ends. Such a drawing is called an embedding of the graph on the surface. Figure 1.21 provides an example of an embedding of a graph on the torus. Embeddings of graphs on surfaces are discussed in Chapter 3 and, more thoroughly, in Chapter 10.

Comment: @quapka But I guess he's talking about the plane.

Comment: I would third Najib.

Comment: A slight correction to your description of Kuratowski's Theorem: A graph is planar if and only if it contains no subgraph that is a *subdivision* of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.